# Plaid: 'client_id must be a properly formatted, non-empty string'

Tags: python, rest, plaid

I am creating an application.

```
PLAID_CLIENT_ID = os.getenv('PLAID_CLIENT_ID')
PLAID_SECRET = os.getenv('PLAID_SECRET')

client = plaid.Client(client_id=PLAID_CLIENT_ID,
                      secret=PLAID_SECRET,
                      environment='development')

access_token = #Access Token

response = client.Accounts.balance.get(access_token)
accounts = response['accounts']

accountsTwo = accounts[0]['balances']['available']
#accountsThree = accountsTwo['balances']
#accountsFour = accountsThree['current']

jsonobj = json.dumps(accounts, indent = 4)

print(jsonobj)
print('-------------------------------------------------')
print(accountsTwo)
```

But I am getting an error saying

```
  File "c:\Users\callm\git\quickstart\python\find.py", line 26, in <module>
    response = client.Accounts.balance.get(access_token)
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\plaid\api\accounts.py", line 22, in get
 line 68, in _http_request
    raise PlaidError.from_response(response_body)
plaid.errors.InvalidRequestError: client_id must be a properly formatted, non-empty string
```

It works fine in the debugger, but when I run it from my terminal it doesn't work. Let me know if you can figure it out please!

Comment: Is your environment different when you run from the debugger?

Comment: No, it was in the same environment. I solved it though. It wasn't working because I didn't import my server.py file. Do you know why that is though?

Comment: The server.py file probably added things to the environment.

Answer (score 0):

For those utilizing the Plaid API Postman Collection and encountering a similar issue, remember to click the "Save" button after updating your client_id and secret_id within your Postman environment